# How to copy element's innerhtml with attributes

Tags: javascript, innerhtml

I need some help about copying a element's innerHTMl text to another element with the attributes. Source element is a text that has html tags such as color and strong (for bold letters), the target element copies the source's elements innerHTML text as is with the html tags such as color and strong (for bold letters)  but it doesn't display the color and bold text (it simply display the plain text) but the source element has the text with the color and bold letters.

I'm using javascript.

Not sure how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

So you can for example transfer all attributes from text1 to text2.

```js
var $text1 = $("#text1");
var $text2 = $("#text2");

var attributes = $text1.prop("attributes");
// loop through text1 attributes and apply them on text2
$.each(attributes, function() {
    $text2.attr(this.name, this.value);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a style="color: red" id="text1"> Hello </a>
<br>
<a id="text2"> World! </a>
```

Comment: Thanks, in your example what If I want text2 to have value as "Hello" also instead of "World" as in your example?. I would like to have text2 exact copy of text1.

Comment: I tried your example with my piece of code it didn't  work not sure what I'm doing wrong. Only difference is I'm using <div tags instead of <a tag.

Comment: my piece of code>>>var divaddprepminsele =  $("#addprepmins");
var divorderpaneladdprepminsele =  $("#orderpaneladdprepmins");
 var attributes1 = divaddprepminsele.prop("attributes");
   $.each(attributes1, function() {
                                    divorderpaneladdprepminsele.attr(this.name, this.value);
                                });

Comment: You forgot the $ before "divaddprepminsele.prop("attributes");".